# within ShGetFolderPathW handles are queried without previously being opened

Tags: c++, winapi, ntdll

I am monitoring some syscalls for `ShGetFolderPathW()`. To do that, I replaced ntdll's `OpenKey`, `CreateKey`, and `QueryValueKey` functions with my own via DLL injection:

```cpp
NTSTATUS NTAPI MyNtOpenKey(PHANDLE KeyHandle, ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,ULONG OpenOptions) {
    auto res = original_nt_open_key_ex(KeyHandle, DesiredAccess, ObjectAttributes, OpenOptions);
    printf("opened %lx\n", (DWORD) *KeyHandle);
    return res;
}

NTSTATUS NTAPI MyNtQueryValueKey(HANDLE KeyHandle, PUNICODE_STRING ValueName,
                                 KEY_VALUE_INFORMATION_CLASS KeyValueInformationClass, PVOID KeyValueInformation,ULONG Length, PULONG ResultLength) {
    printf("query %lx\n", (DWORD)KeyHandle);
    auto res = original_nt_query_value_key(KeyHandle, ValueName, KeyValueInformationClass,
                                             KeyValueInformation, Length, ResultLength);
    return res;
}
```

I see calls like:

```
opened 224
opened 228
...
queried 228
queried 228
opened 0
opened 224
opened 22c
opened 0
opened 22c
queried 22c
queried 230
queried 230
queried e4
queried 230
queried 230
```

How is it possible that handles `230` and `e4` are queried without being open, when the documentation states that they must be opened beforehand?

Here are syscalls monitored with API Monitor between **queried 22c** and  **queried 230**:

```
#   Time of Day Thread  Module  API Return Type Return Value    Duration
181 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  NtQueryValueKey ( 0x0000020c, 0x005bf470, KeyValuePartialInformation, 0x005bf3b0, 0x0000008e, 0x005bf388 )  NTSTATUS    STATUS_SUCCESS  0.0000044
182 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  memmove ( 0x0092c0a0, 0x005bf3bc, 0x00000068 )  void*   0x0092c0a0  0.0000001
183 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  RtlNtStatusToDosError ( STATUS_SUCCESS )    ULONG   ERROR_SUCCESS   0.0000001
184 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  RtlExpandEnvironmentStrings ( NULL, "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs", 0x00000033, "䶑ʚ濾㥨", 0x00000800, 0x005be2d0 ) NTSTATUS    STATUS_SUCCESS  0.0000020
185 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  NtQueryInformationToken ( 0xfffffffc, TokenStatistics, 0x005be248, 0x00000038, 0x005be244 ) NTSTATUS    STATUS_SUCCESS  0.0000012
186 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  RtlAllocateHeap ( 0x00920000, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 0x0000004c )    PVOID   0x0092c0a0  0.0000011
187 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  NtQueryInformationToken ( 0xfffffffc, TokenUser, 0x0092c0a0, 0x0000004c, 0x005be244 )   NTSTATUS    STATUS_SUCCESS  0.0000008
188 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  RtlEqualSid ( 0x0092c0a8, 0x7ef90fe0 )  BOOLEAN TRUE    0.0000003
189 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  RtlFreeHeap ( 0x00920000, 0x00000000, 0x0092c0a0 )  BOOLEAN TRUE    0.0000006
190 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive ( 0x7760888c )   VOID        0.0000002
191 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive ( 0x7760888c )   VOID        0.0000001
192 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  memset ( 0x005be050, 0x00000000, 0x00000208 )   void*   0x005be050  0.0000001
193 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  RtlIntegerToUnicodeString ( 0x000602ff, 0x00000010, 0x005bd7a0 )    NTSTATUS    STATUS_SUCCESS  0.0000005
194 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  RtlInitUnicodeString ( 0x005bdb98, "000602xx" ) VOID        0.0000001
195 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  memset ( 0x005bdde0, 0x00000000, 0x00000214 )   void*   0x005bdde0  0.0000001
196 3:29:45.879 PM  1   KERNELBASE.dll  NtQueryValueKey ( 0x000000f0, 0x005bdb98, KeyValueFullInformation, 0x005bdde0, 0x00000214, 0x005bdba4 ) NTSTATUS    STATUS_SUCCESS  0.0000052
```

Comment: Please only tag the language you're actually program in. The code you show means different things in C and C++.

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: "*How is it possible that handles 230 and e4 are queried without being open*" - they are likely being opened by other means that you are not hooking yet.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what can it be then?

Comment: Who knows. Maybe the OS is using other private APIs to open the keys in different ways thean you are expecting. You are digging deep into the OS's internals here.